# React-router-Dom useNavigate re-render problem

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am making a map application. It is a full page map application.  In the application, I pass the states to redux via the url search parameters.
I render components conditionally with state on redux.

The search parameters change with each movement on the map.
e.g =>  http://localhost:8080/?map=2d&lng=28.751577606036108&lat=41.117485501450204&z=10&bearing=10&pitch=0

=> http://localhost:8080/?map=2d&lng=28.753937232765566&lat=40.981906338895925&z=14.856764993412996&bearing=-111.59999999999997&pitch=42.000000000000014

everything else in the application is displayed on the sidebar. sidebar has several states and these states are rendered via dynamic url
e.g => The main view of the sidebar comes in this url directory.   "http://localhost:8080/?map=2d&lng=29.038691&lat=41.055667&z=10&bearing=10&pitch=0"

The detail status of the sidebar is displayed via this url. "http://localhost:8080/detail/2?map=2d"

I have some cards that are about to be triggered in the main state of the sidebar.
I am doing the click function using useNavigate.
however, my cards are re-rendered because the search parameters change with each map movement.

what do i need to do to fix this.?
Thank you

useNavigateSearch.js

```
import {createSearchParams, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const useNavigateSearch = () =\> {
const navigate = useNavigate();
return (pathname, params) =\>
navigate({ pathname, search: `?${createSearchParams(params)}` });
> };

export default useNavigateSearch;
```

Card.js

```
import useNavigateSearch from "../../../hooks/useNavigateSearch";

const Card = ({title, img, color, route,id}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigateSearch();
    console.log('render')

    const handleClick = (route,id) => {
        navigate(`${route}/${id}`, {map: '2d'})
    }
    return (

        <div className="w-24 h-20 mt-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center cursor-pointer"
             onClick={()=> handleClick(route,id)}>
                <div className={`w-12 h-12 ${color} rounded-full flex justify-center items-center`}>
                    <img src={img} className="w-8 h-8 brightness-0 invert"/>
                </div>
                <div className="text-sm">
                    {title}
                </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: have you checked out https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/start/tutorial.md

Comment: You know, when you console log ***outside*** any component lifecycle method/hook that it's not an accurate measure by any means how often a component is *rendered to the DOM*, right? Move `console.log('render')` into a `useEffect` hook to see how many times the component is actually being rendered. Are you seeing any measurable performance degradation? In other words, have you done a performance audit, both before and after a "fix" to see if any performance has been improved?

Comment: @DrewReese I did not do any performance checks.  I just saw that when I type "console.log('render')" it occurs every time for the card. In useEffect, it is rendered only once.  I'm worried that this will affect performance later on through the Dom. Will it be a problem if I continue like this?

Comment: In React, 1 render cycle === 1 `useEffect` hook call. Just to be clear, you used something like `useEffect(() => { console.log('render'); });` with no dependency array? Sorry, I should have been more specific. If you see only a single console log then I don't see an issue here. I don't see any issue/potential problem with the code you've shared.

Answer (score 1):

That is, unfortunately, the way useNavigate is designed. If the url changes, every component that uses useNavigate will rerender. There's an issue tracked on their github page discussing this: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7634

The latest advice from Ryan Florance (co-creator of react-router) is that if you use version 6.4 you can create a custom BrowserRouter which you export, and then instead of using `useNavigate`, you import that router and call `.navigate` on it:

> This issue can be solved with the new routers in 6.4.
>
> ```
> import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
> const router = createBrowserRouter([ /* ... routes ... */ ]):
> export { router }
> ```
>
> ```
> import { router } from "./router";
>
> // call this anywhere you want in your app,
> // it's outside of the react render cycle and will
> // never change
> router.navigate("/anywhere/you/want");
> ```

See: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7634#issuecomment-1306650156